# Windows key is not passed through to XWindows on MobaXterm

Tags: windows-10, mobaxterm

I'm using MobaXterm on Windows 10 in order to have Xwindows.

My configuration uses the `windows` key (also called `super` key) extensively, but the Windows 10 operating system is capturing it rather than passing it through. For example, `windows`-`tab` brings up the Windows task view, instead of whatever is configured in Xwindows.

Is there a way to configure MobaXterm to capture it instead?

Comment: This new behavior old existing behavior?  Have you verified, you don't need to use a modifier key, in order to pass the windows key?

Comment: It's my first attempt at using MobaXterrm, so not sure about the old behavior. Have used VMs in the past, which have an option to capture all keys (including the Windows key), or let the host operating system process the keys first. In my case, I don't want Windows to process them first.

Comment: Well you are not using a VM so how it will work is indeed different, which means, you likely need to either set a modifier key or use the currently configured modifier key.

Comment: I am able to change the modifier key in linux to use the alt key instead, but this isn't a permanent solution as the alt key is used for things other than xwindows functions. If MobaXterm doesn't support capturing all keys, I can search for another Xwindowing solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to use vcxsrv. Add `-keyhook` to the target of the properties of the shortcut. As I'm using the `i3` windows manager, also needed to remove `-multiwindow`.

If anyone has an answer for how to make MobaXterm work, I'll accept the answer.